# Indy. sending Attach pdf by stream

Tags: delphi, pdf, stream, indy

I'm having trouble sending attachments via stream.
I use Indy 10.6.2 and Delphi Berlin.
The mail consists of html with attached images, plus one or more PDF files inserted directly from the database.
I don't get any errors in the process.
Mail is sent seamlessly, but attached PDFs are not received.

I look forward to comments

```
 Msg := TIdMessage.Create(self);
  try
    Msg.ContentType := 'multipart/mixed';
    Msg.From.Name := FromName;
    Msg.From.Address := FromAddress;
    Msg.Priority := mpHigh;
    Msg.Subject := Asunto;

    with TIdMessageBuilderHtml.Create do
      try
        if FMsgTxtPlnPac <> '' then
          PlainText.Text := FMsgTxtPlnPac;

        if FMsgHtmlPac <> '' then
        begin
          Html.Text := FMsgHtmlPac;
          n := 0;
          for s in FMsgHTMLFiles.Split([',']) do
          begin
            n := Succ(n);
            c := 'img' + inttostr(n);
            HTMLFiles.Add(s, c); // cid de imagen en HTML(cid:img1, cid:img2...)
          end;

        end;

        if AttachFiles <> '' then
          for s in AttachFiles.Split([',']) do
            Attachments.Add(s);

        // Attach from DB
        while not dm.qryBlb.Eof do
        begin
          Attach := TIdAttachmentMemory.Create(Msg.MessageParts);
          Attach.ContentType := 'application/pdf';
          Attach.FileName := dm.qryBlb.FieldByName('nombre_archivo').AsString;
          Attach.LoadFromStream(dm.GetDataBlbStrm('DATA_TXT')); // this ok in attach.datastream.size
          Attach.CloseLoadStream;    
          dm.qryBlb.Next;
        end;

        FillMessage(Msg);
      finally
        Free;
      end;

    for s in FMailPac.Split([',']) do
    begin
      EmailAddress := Trim(s);
      if EmailAddress <> '' then
      begin
        with Msg.recipients.Add do
        begin
          Address := EmailAddress;
        end;
      end;
    end;

    for s in MailCC.Split([',']) do
    begin
      EmailAddress := Trim(s);
      if EmailAddress <> '' then
        Msg.CCList.Add.Address := EmailAddress;
    end;

    for s in MailCCO.Split([',']) do
    begin
      EmailAddress := Trim(s);
      if EmailAddress <> '' then
        Msg.BccList.Add.Address := EmailAddress;
    end;

 finally
   SMTP1.Send(Msg);
 end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TIdMessageBuilderHtml` supports adding attachments via streams, as well as via files.  However, those streams have to remain alive for the duration that the `TIdCustomMessageBuilder.Attachments` collection is populated, which is not an option in your case since you are looping through DB records one at a time, thus you would only be able to access 1 DB stream at a time.

You could create a local array/list of `TMemoryStream` objects, and then populate the `TMessageBuilderHtml` with those streams, but you will end up wasting a lot of memory that way since `TIdMessageBuilderHtml` would make its own copy of the `TMemoryStream` data.  And there is no way to have `TIdMessageBuilderHtml` just use your `TMemoryStream` data as-is in a read-only mode (hmm, I wonder if I should add that feature!).

The reason why your manual `TIdAttachmentMemory` objects don't work is simply because `TIdCustomMessageBuilder.FillMessage()` clears the `TIdMessage`'s body before then re-populating it, thus losing your attachments (and various other properties that you are setting manually beforehand).

You would have to add your DB attachments to the `TIdMessage` *after* `FillMessage()` has done its work first.  But, then you risk `TIdMessageBuilderHtml` not setting up the `TIdMessage` structure properly since it wouldn't know your DB attachments exist.

On a side note, you are not using `TIdAttachmentMemory` correctly anyway.  Do not call its `CloseLoadStream()` method if you have not called its `OpenLoadStream()` method first.  Calling its `LoadFromStream()` method is enough in this case (or, you can even pass the `TStream` to `TIdAttachmentMemory`'s constructor).  Do note, however, that you are leaking the `TStream` returned by `dm.GetDataBlbStrm()`.

So, in this case, you are probably better off simply populating the `TIdMessage` manually and not use `TIdMessageBuilderHtml` at all.  Or, you could derive a new class from `TIdMessageBuilderHtml` (or `TIdCustomMessageBuilder` directly) and override its virtual `FillBody()` and `FillHeaders()` methods to take your DB streams into account.